# Document AI doesn't recognize parent label area correctly, and does it only on per line basis

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I have an issue with Document AI. When I try to create Parent label, with child labels in it, it does not recognize whole area of parent label correctly, and only recongizes it on per line basis, with separate label for each.

Can it be done somehow that it recognize both lines in one parent label insteand of dividing it?

Here is an example of how AI labeled it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here I have provided example on how I labeled the "Training/Testing" datasets:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't that the AI that can't work out which telescope did what? So can see why it might get parent & child mixed...

Comment: Hi, can I ask do you have any idea for better AI document recognition?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the images provided of the training data, it looks like the labels are not very precise. The bounding boxes need to be tight around the entities in the document, and cover the full text required.

Are you using uptraining with an Invoice/Purchase Order processor or a Custom Document Extractor? Based on the document structure I can see, it might make sense to use Uptraining if it's similar to an existing processor.

It's also recommended to provide as much training data as possible to improve accuracy. If you're using the minimum amount required, your results could be improved by adding more labeled data.

You can try leveraging [Auto-Labeling](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/label-documents#auto-label) to create more examples quickly without having to manually label everything.